# Inverse Matrix calculation using iterative method

Tags: c, matrix, matrix-inverse

My professor's assigned us a lab that I've been stumped on and can find nothing for help on the web. It's specifically for a matrix with an eigenvalue < 1.

Given the 3x3 matrix   A = {(.5, -1, 0), (0, .6666, 0), (.5, -1, .6666)}, you're supposed to compute the inverse using A^-1 =I + B + B^2 + B^3.....B^20, where I is the identity matrix and B = I - A. There are two outputs, one being A^-1, and the other being A * A^-1 to check the result.

So far, I've tried two different functions for multiplication. Sorry for my terrible naming. i, j, and k are the row, column, and loop counter respectively.

```
void mPower(double x[][3], double y[][3], double z[][3])
{
  int i, j, k;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)   {
      for (k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        z[i][j] = z[i][j] + (x[i][k] * y[k][j]);
}
}
```

mPower is my probably wrong function for multiplication. As an alternative I've tried

```
void multiplyMatrix(double x[][3], double y[][3], double z[][3])
{
  int i, j, k;
   int sum = 0;

for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
     sum = 0;
     for (k = 0; k <= 2; k++) {
        sum = sum + x[i][k] * y[k][j];
     }
     z[i][j] = sum;
  }
  }

}
```

However, I get only zeros.

```
void printIt(double a[][3], double b[][3])
{
 int i, j;

 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
     printf ("\n\t\t\t");
     for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
         printf ("%7.4f", a[i][j]);
     printf ("\t");
     for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
         printf ("%7.4f", b[i][j]);
         printf ("\n\n\t");
 }
}

int main()
{
  int i, j, k;
  double b1[][3] = {.5, 1., 0., 0., .6666, 0., -.5, -1., .6666};
  double b3[3][3] = {0};
  double addOn[3][3];
  double aInverse[3][3];
  double identity[][3] = {1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.};
  mPower (b1, b1, b3);
  for (k = 0; k < 20; k++)     {
      addOn[i][j] = addOn[i][j] + b3[i][j];
      mPower (b1, addOn, b3);
}

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)  {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        aInverse[i][j] = identity[i][j] + addOn[i][j];
}

printIt(b3, aInverse);
system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

PrintIt has at least made the display formatting to be nice, but I'm worried about the for loops in my main problem. I just can't wrap my head around what to do. I'm getting values all over the place, and I'm really having a hard time figuring out the math involved for such a niche problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to fix your logic (and the resulting code is very inefficient and can be much better written).  Some issues I think I found are:

1. Variable addOn was not initialized
2. Your b was incorrect (bad subtraction) given the definition of B=I-A in your preface.
3. Your accumulation of addOn = addOn + b3 was not in a double loop using
   uninitialized i and j.
4. You do not seem to have the inverse check (a * a^-1)=I

(Note, I am getting a -0.000 because we are using IEEE double precision numbers so math is not exact especially when it comes to thirds.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mPower(double x[3][3], double y[3][3], double z[3][3])
{
  int i, j, k;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)   {
      z[i][j] = 0;
      for (k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        z[i][j] += (x[i][k] * y[k][j]);
}
}

void mAdd(double x[3][3], double y[3][3]) 
{
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)  
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
       x[i][j] += y[i][j];
}

void mCopy(double x[3][3], double y[3][3]) 
{
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)  
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
       x[i][j] = y[i][j];
}

void printIt(double a[3][3], double b[3][3])
{
 int i, j;

 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
     printf ("\n\t\t\t");
     for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
         printf ("%7.4f", a[i][j]);
     printf ("\t");
     for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
         printf ("%7.4f", b[i][j]);
         printf ("\n\n\t");
 }
}

int main()
{
  int i, j, k;
  double a[3][3] = {.5, -1., 0., 0., .6666, 0., .5, -1., .6666};
  double b1[3][3] = {.5, 1., 0., 0., 1-.6666, 0., -.5, 1., 1-.6666};
  double b3[3][3] = {0};
  double addOn[3][3] = {0};
  double aInverse[3][3] = {0};
  double identity[][3] = {1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.};
printIt(aInverse, b1);
  mAdd( aInverse, identity );
printIt(aInverse, b1);
  mCopy( b3, b1 );
  mCopy( addOn, b1 );
  for (k = 0; k < 20; k++)     {
    mAdd( aInverse, addOn );
    mPower(b3, b1, addOn);
    mCopy( b3, addOn );
printf( "loop iteration %d\n", k );
printIt(aInverse, addOn );
}
printf( "aInverse\n" );
printIt(b1, aInverse);
printf( "verify\n");
mPower(a,aInverse,b3);
printIt(a,b3);

return 0;
}
```

Results I got:

```
aInverse

         0.5000 1.0000 0.0000    2.0000 3.0003 0.0000


         0.0000 0.3334 0.0000    0.0000 1.5002 0.0000


        -0.5000 1.0000 0.3334   -1.5001 0.0000 1.5002

verify

         0.5000-1.0000 0.0000    1.0000-0.0000 0.0000


         0.0000 0.6666 0.0000    0.0000 1.0000 0.0000


         0.5000-1.0000 0.6666    0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
```

Comment: Oh wow, you blew the math out of the water. I accidentally posted an older version with my mPower function which is why addOn wasn't initialized, but other than that you've shown me a lot. Thank you. How are you getting -1.5001 and a positive 3.003, though?

Comment: Actually, I found it! The first 1. in b1 should be negative and the -.5 should be positive.